# need help finding the max value in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, max

I am trying to find the max integer of an array where number = [10]. My method prints out 0, not the max integer.

```
public static void maxArr (int[] number){ 
        int max = number[0];
        for(int i = 1; i<number.length; i++){
            if(number[i]> max){
                max = number[i];
            }
        } System.out.print(max);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show how is maxArr being called and input array?

Comment: Your method looks fine, the problem might be how you call it.

Comment: Have you actually put any values into the array?  `number = [10]` looks more like a declaration of the array, not it's contents...

Comment: int N = 10; 
  
    int[] array = new int [N];  maxArr(array);

Comment: @perldog93 your array has all 0 values! What did you expect? The JVM will do a magic spell to fill it with random values? Or maybe you though it would be like C/C++ array initialization?

Comment: You are creating an empty array with this line.

Comment: You can use a `for-loop` to set initial values in your array, using `Math.random()*9001` to fill the values could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't filling your array correctly.

In java, when you first create an array with `private int[] myArray`, it is null (that is, it doesn't represent an actual thing yet, it's just a name that *could* point to an array in the future). Next, you somehow tell it how many elements it will hold. There are 2 commonly used ways to do this:

The first is something that looks like `myArray = new int[42];` This will *initialize* the array, but every slot will be zero (or worse, null if it's an array of Objects). You can fill one of its individual slots (in this case, the 4th slot) with `myArray[3] = 13`. This will store the int 13 in slot 3 of myArray. Array slots start counting at 0, so if you want the first element you call `myArray[0]`, if you want the second one you call `myArray[1]`, and so on. You can use a for loop to populate an entire array with just a few lines of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i] = 10;
}
```

Your array is now ready to be used for whatever its purpose in life happens to be.

The second way to fill your array happens when you initialize it. It looks like `myArray = new int[] {10, 42, 24, 64, 8, 16, 3};` Anything you put into the curly brackets is now in the array, so the value of `myArray[0]` is now 10, and the value of `myArray[1]` is now 42, and so on.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, this really clears things up for me. I am just learning arrays and was pretty confused.

Answer (score 1):

Error is in the usage of your method. Otherwise it looks fine.

```
int[] array = new int[1]
array[0] = 10
maxArr(array)
```

is what you tried to do, and it will print 10.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] array = new int [N];
```

That initializes all the elements of `array` to the default value of `int` which is 0.

So, you get 0 as max.

Answer (score 0):

This initializes all elements to 0.

```
int N = 10;
int[] array = new int[N]
maxArray(array)
```

If you want to initialize it with 10, you should

```
int[] array= {10};
maxArray(array) //This should print 10
```

Comment: @sashkello *find the max integer of an array where number = [10]*, if all the elements have the same value, it's not an answer. Instead, it's like copy/paste another actual answers.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Just badly formulated question, it was meant to be {10}, that is array of one element and max value always 10.

Comment: If you want to show OP how to initialize an array to find the max value, at least provide a basic sample code filling the arrays with values from 1 to 10. Having all the array values equals won't help.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza- I agree I should, but was trying to answer it more precisely using the data from question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of

```
int[] array = new int[]{10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
maxArray(array);
```

Should now print "10"